# "Oni nomas tiujn videojn videoblogoj" or "Oni nomas tiujn videojn videoblogo"?

Tags: word-usage, plurals

When we are describing something with a verb such as *nomi*, should the plurality (-j) of the described object be respected?

Answer (score 6):

According to PMEG (http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/perverba/objekto.html) the -j must be there.  The relevant example from PMEG (Actually from Fabeloj de Andersen) is

*Jam en ilia infaneco oni ja nomadis ilin gefianĉoj.*

The reasoning is that if you change the sentence to use *estas*, you clearly would have the plural there.  "Ili estas videoblogoj".  It is really the same rule for "ili estas" as it is for "oni nomas ilin".

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on what you mean. There is nothing in the grammar of Esperanto saying that a noun describing several things must be plural. If every one of those videos is a video blog, then *videoblogoj* is OK. But it seems more natural to me that a *videoblogo* is the collection of *tiuj videoj*, at least this is how I understand *videoblogo*, and I would write *Oni nomas tiujn videojn videoblogo*.

You could compare

- *Tiuj 10 homoj estas unu grupo.*
- *Tiuj 10 homoj estas du grupoj: unu konsistas el 4. la alia el 6 homoj.*

This is different from

- *Tiuj 10 homoj estas feliĉaj*
- *Oni opinias tiujn videojn bonaj*

where you have to write *feliĉaj, bonaj*.

Answer (score 5):

My sense here is that they would both be plural. Here's a similar example from the *Fundamenta Krestomatio*.

- *al la germanaj poŝtaj oficistoj, kiuj nomas tiujn ĉi gazetajn sendaĵojn “bastonoj”.*